# Why are there three partitions on my hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

Why does my laptop have three partitions while there is only one hard drive in it?

Since I upgraded from Windows 7 to 10 on this same laptop, when I go in the windows defragmentation utility, there are three partitions thats shows up:

- The main (C:) partition
- The "System" partition
- Another drive named weirdly " \?\Volume{9a3a97..." with a bunch of numbers and letters

I don't understand why the two other paritions other than the C: drive are there.

Comment: why did I get a downvote? ....

Comment: probably because your title is bad and also your question lags a precise asked question. ... maybe someone considered your question too "dumb" ... but to answer your question why you have 3 drives: it is called "partitioning" see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning ... in regard of your optimization question: windows 7 and later will optimize the disks if needed in the background while you do not use the pc

Comment: Could it be possible that I never had these 2 others partition before the windows 10 upgrade?

Comment: @masgo - I wouldn't say its "dumb" nor should anyone.  Confusing and not clear perhaps is the better term.

Comment: @MartinB. - That is really only something you can tell us.

Comment: I edited your question so it's a little clearer. Feel free to make any changes if you see it necessary by clicking "edit".

Answer (score 3):

The main question has been already answered by **@masgo**: there are the three partitions and NOT the physical three new drives.

> Could it be possible that I never had these 2 others partition before the windows 10 upgrade?

Yes, it is possible:

> When installing a Windows operating system (OS) on a hard drive, and
>   if you use Windows Setup to create new partition on an MBR disk,
>   **Windows will create a system reserved partition**, and if it is a GPT
>   disk, then Windows will create a recovery partition and a EFI system
>   partition without drive letter. The recovery partition on Windows 10
>   consumes about 450MB, Windows 8/8.1 200MB, and Windows 7 100MB.

You can take a look at [this article](http://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/recovery-partition-after-upgrading-to-windows-10-4348.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is an simple thing. This has occurred because of partitions while you **upgraded** from **Windows 7 to Windows 10**.[image]

### Answer:

You can go to **Disk Management** and fix it.

### To access Disk Management

Use Windows+R to open Run, type diskmgmt.msc in the empty box and tap OK. Way 3: Open Disk Management in Computer Management. Step 1: Right-click This PC and choose Manage in the context menu to enter Computer Management. Step 2: Select Disk Management on the left.

### What to do after you access Disk Management:

[image]

**Shrink The Partition.**
**//These are NOT Physical Drives//**